# wso2 database refresh on nodes (active - active deployment)

Tags: wso2-api-manager

hi @channel i have an interesting issue here , so i am using active active deployment with 2 nodes for web and 2 nodes for gateway , so when i deploy an api via the publisher it gets deployed on 1 node , and when i restart the other node thats when it also gets deployed on that node ,  i am using a loadbalancer in place to control and manage the traffic, is there a way to configure the apim to actually deploy on both nodes with out having to restart the other node?

restart one node after the other has deployed